# UrlFetchApp.Fetch non standard port

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, port

Hope someone can help.

I need to return some data from a RESTful API service that is hosted on a non standard port 9091. I am using the following as a test harness:

```
var options = {
    'method' : 'GET'
  };

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://testfetch.cmi.org.uk:9091',options);

  Logger.log(result);
```

And I recieve an error `Address unavailable: http://testfetch.cmi.<?>:9091`

If i changed to:

```
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://testfetch.cmi.org.uk:80',options);
```

The call works correctly. I presume that google block outbound traffic on non standard ports, is there any way to open a port as unfortunately I have no control over how the RESTful API service is hosted.

Any help with this much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you open the link in your browser?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes it works fine in the browser, just not when using UrlFetchApp.fetch from google script. I have a feeling Google only allow outbound connections on port 80 and 443.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. Can you connect with that port using any other tool - like curl or postman at 9091?

Comment: Yes Postman connects fine. I have managed a work around using IIS as a reverse proxy, receiving the request on port 443 and passing to the API on port 9091. Not ideal but at least I can call the restful service from a google script. Many thanks for your response.